# Seeking a proven explicit or closed form upper bound on the infinite product of the Zeta function over the natural numbers, 2 to infinity

Tags: riemann-zeta, infinite-product

I'm interested in upper bounds on the product $\prod_{n=2}^\infty \zeta(n)$

The following post was very helpful and from the answers I see I'll need to study up on partitions to learn more about this particular infinite product:

[Infinite product of Zetafunctions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4056563/infinite-product-of-zetafunctions)

Understanding that the actual limit of the product may never be expressible in closed form, for now I'm just hoping to learn if there is ANY proven closed-form upper bound. Say for example could someone have shown that $\prod_{n=2}^\infty \zeta(n)<e$, hypothetically.

Or even a rational number to as many digits as possible. If anyone has provided any values in a paper. I'm really just looking for a nailed down explicit value to the greatest accuracy known so far.

Comment: See also https://oeis.org/A021002

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the log of your product is the sum of $\log\zeta_n$.  Each term is less than $\zeta_n-1$ so, by the other post, the log of your product is less than one.

Answer (score 1):

$$\prod_{n=2}^\infty \zeta(n)=2.294856591673313794183\cdots$$
$$\sum _{n=2}^\infty \log (\zeta (n))=0.830670354271780112508\cdots$$